# Locating a multi-line image inline with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS positioning problem that’s probably very simple, but for the life of me I can’t work out how to solve. I need to position images at a particular point in the text flow, but they are larger than the line height so I want the text below them to wrap around them. I can’t use basic floats because (see the example), they need to be exactly at the anchor point, but the minute I start putting them in wrappers I fall victim to the collapsed height of float-only containers which I can’t work out how to cancel.

Any advice welcomed. I’ve uploaded an image of the print version (this for an EPUB version of a book) to show what I want.

Thanks!

[Print version with inline image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJqPt.png)

Comment: CSS cannot do it, unfortunately.  You can wrap around one side of an image or shape, like this: https://codepen.io/nailaahmad/pen/jorKC.  But not both sides.

Comment: I feared that was the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make some container and set-up some `margin-left` `margin-right` `margin-top` but i still need more information for better help

Comment: What extra info can I supply you with? I’m not sure about using margins for positioning, because I have no control over the overall container width and thus the text flow, as this will be rendered in ebook readers, where the users have considerable control over rendering options.